# Eclipse and Android error 'parseSdkContent failed'

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

Having this issue since I upgraded the `Android Tools` to 21.1. When I start eclipse, even in a clean workspace, I get the error `parseSdkContent failed` and the details say:

```
com.android.sdklib.devices.DeviceManager.createInstance
(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/android/utils/ILogger;)
Lcom/android/sdklib/devices/DeviceManager;
```

I have searched the internet and tried almost every solution but to no avail. When I go to Android preferences and try to set the path to the SDK , it says no target available. Is there anything else that I can try? I can't do any of my Android Development until it's fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I just deleted eclipse and reinstalled. Lost all of my settings etc. but it's all I could do. Something must have gotten corrupted in the upgrade of the ADT.

Comment: Instead of losing all of the settings, you could just backup the "org.eclipse.core.runtime" folder , which is found on "workspace\.metadata\.plugins" .

Answer (score 17):

Step 1. Find the folder named: `.android`

This folder can be located in your Windows user directory, for example in Windows 7 or 8:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_WINDOWS_USERNAME\.android
```

Step 2. Delete this folder `.android`

Step 3. Restart Eclipse and your problem will be solved.

Comment: i tried this it worked in my case.it was due to xml naming issue  http://www.blazin.in/2013/03/android-parsesdkcontent-failed-error.html

Answer (score 14):

---

> You DON'T have to delete ANYTHING

---

For me updating the DDMS from ADT plugin did the trick!

Before that, to save time I only updated **ADT plugin**, nothing else like Android DDMS, TraceView etc., so I ran into same issue.

After a couple of restarts and Google searches everyone was proposing different solutions. I updated my **Android DDMS** and restarted eclipse ***and it worked like a charm!***

I didn't have to remove my workspace or update my .project file etc.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after installing 21.1 on a new machine. Solved it by deleting the default workspace I created during the first launch and then re-starting ADT as Administrator, recreating the workspace. After closing and re-running it as a normal user the problem disappeared.

Comment: Did not even delete anything. Apparently, running Eclipse as Administrator does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Re-installing the new version of ADT (which at the time is ADT-23.0.3.zip(http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)) helped me with the same problem you are described above. This message may be a little to late but hope this can also help others.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling API 21 and installing API 19 worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! Uninstalling API 21 via Android SDK Manager worked for me, too. I have API 20 installed, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, use the Check For Updates item in the Help menu to update the Eclipse-part of your Android tools (called ADT).

Comment: I've done that already. I deleted all of the plugins I had installed and reinstalled them. I updated the eclipse platform, plugin's etc. not making a difference

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to your eclipse workspace and delete the .meta folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently having the same problem and i figured it out that one must install/update other necessary software related to ADT.Suppose you are updating your ADT then you must also update DDMS with it.So,best option is to install the all software/plugin pack for the version you are updating.

When you uninstall the full thing and install it again,all of these related software get installed in same version so it always solves the problem.

According to me re installing should be final solution.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine fixed by, before restarting your IDE, make your activity main layout as the current tab open, then restart your IDE. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

**This did it for me.**

In Eclipse go to

**Project Properties** -> **Java Compiler** and set '**Compiler Compliance Level**' to 1.7

Answer (score 0):

For me I delete Android 5(API 21) installed software packages from SDK manager.
I am working on API 20 ( Android 4.4w.2). It only solved my problem completely.
Delete .android folder or others didnt help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting ".android" is temporarily fixing the problem with me as after sometime it begins to come again ..

Here is another cause and fix that might help .. This is happening because of existence of 2 versions of SDK in the same machine but in case you have only one version (probably it is 21) just download the SDK platform for API 20 (4.4W) as there is a problem in 21's "layoutlib.jar"). start applying the following:

Close Eclipse

Navigate to your sdk folder (something like C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk)

Go to platforms folder -> android-21 folder -> data folder and rename layoutlib.jar (for backup only)

Copy the same file (layoutlib.jar) from your android-20 folder to this folder "android-21"

Start Eclipse

Answer (score -1):

maybe you have more than one android IDE installed,  for example ,you installed android studio and adt+ eclipse all,just remove one can fix this problem