# Android sdk content loader error

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I am using **eclipse juno** version on win 7 32 bit platform.

Everything was going fine, till today when I started Eclipse, the Android sdk content loader could not exceed more than 0%. I tried to restart eclipse, I ended up the adb process and restarted eclipse again.

But the **sdk content loader is not geting loaded**. There is no progress at all.

Could any one please help me in this?

Comment: Can you verify the URL ? if it is https or http

Comment: In the directory that your worskspace goes in there is a .metadata directory.  In this there is a .log file -- have you checked what is at the end of this?

Comment: maybe u can reference this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097701/eclipse-and-android-error-parsesdkcontent-failed

Answer (score 3):

**Go in the task manager and delete the adb process..then restart you eclipse...**

This might work. And refer to below link

[Getting error message “Android sdk content loader stuck at 0%”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360824/getting-error-message-android-sdk-content-loader-stuck-at-0)

Comment: I tried deleting adb process and restarting eclipse. But all in vani. What I got across is, ** delete your debug keystore :
%USERPROFILE%/.android on Windows.** But where can i find that in my system?

Comment: in Windows 7 it will be under C:\Users\Ruchi\.android\debug.keystore

Comment: I deleted debug keystore. But no luck yet. SDK content loader doesnt exceed from 0%! Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried this -> Go in the task manager and delete the adb process..then restart you eclipse

Comment: @Nirali Yup , I tried that too. Today, I installed eclipse and sdk manager again and started from scratch. But the newly installed eclipse is throwing the same problem. It gets hanged at the phase **loading data for Android 4.2 Widgets and Layouts.** Can someone please provide a solution?