# Android SDK Content Loader error in Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I work on eclipse IDE which takes long time to load and I face this issue every time I open Eclipse. I deleted cache folder and ddms.cfg file from .android folder but still it shows this same error. Kindly let me know how to rectify this issue.

Comment: your ans is unclear. please first you should search make sure you will get your answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android sdk content loader error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334552/android-sdk-content-loader-error)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change **eclipse.ini** file configuration of memory. it may  help you.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to either you using system contain lesser RAM.. For the proper speed it need minimum 4 GB RAM. OR you using old version of IDE.

Please refer this http://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform_UI/Juno_Performance_Investigation